# Import item and delete old item only

Tags: import, delete-row

Import or update if item is exists in MySQL table.

Sample import:

```
Jon | 12
Marie | 17
Delia | 10
Megan | 2
```

In MySQL table:

```
Jon | 12
chrtalie | 23
```

How delete record if not exists in Sapmle - `chrtalie | 23`? 
It's about more than 2000 item`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options:

1. Clear the table before the import.
2. Import into a temporary copy of the original table, and merge the two tables manually:

   1. Create an empty copy of the original table
   2. Import into the copy
   3. Delete from the original table the entries that are not in the copy
   4. Update the entries in the original table that are in the copy
   5. Add in the original table the entries that are only in the copy
   6. Drop the copy table